# Adding tags to WooCommerce products through Rest Api

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding products to WooCommerce through the code below
`https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#create-a-product`

```
<?php
$data = [
    'name' => 'my title',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'regular_price' => '19',
    'description' => 'my description',
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 9
        ],
    ],
    'tags' => [
        [
            'name' => 'my tag',
        ],
    ],

];

print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));
?>
```

Now I have some tags that are like this: (The number of tags is variable and they are in an array)

```
array (size=3)
  'tag1' => string 'tag1' (length=4)
  'tag2' => string 'tag2' (length=4)
  'tag3' => string 'tag3' (length=4)
```

I want all these tags to be sent to WooCommerce when creating a product.
I put the array in the code above, it gets a key of 0 and it is not sent. what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe syntax error ?
In this example I'm using ids and not slug/name of tags.

```
<?php
    $data = [
      'name' => 'my title',
      'type' => 'simple',
      'regular_price' => '19',
      'description' => 'my description',
      'categories' => [
        [
          'id' => 9
        ],
      ],
      'tags' => [
        ['id' => 'TAG_ID_int',
        ],
        ['id' => 'TAG_ID_int',
        ],
      ],

    ];

    print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));
    ?>
```

Comment: What's the ID? I want to add new tags. So the name of the tags must be entered

Comment: If you are adding that already exists, you can send the ids

Comment: They do not already exist. I want to add new tags.